# Maven: How to create temporary folders?

Tags: java, maven

I am using `sql-maven-plugin` to execute `SQL` for my integration tests and it looks like

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sql-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>${dataSource.url}</url>
                            <!-- no transaction -->
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>CREATE TABLE User
                            (
                                id             VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                userExternalId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                email          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                clientId       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                clientSecret   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                active         BOOLEAN,
                                PRIMARY KEY (id)
                            )</sqlCommand>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                        <version>${h2.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <driver>${dataSource.driver}</driver>
                    <url>${dataSource.url}</url>
                    <username>${dataSource.user}</username>
                    <password>${dataSource.password}</password>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

The way I configure datasource is

```
            <configuration>
                <driver>${dataSource.driver}</driver>
                <url>${dataSource.url}</url>
                <username>${dataSource.user}</username>
                <password>${dataSource.password}</password>
            </configuration>
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, I see issues as

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.022s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 14 16:13:20 UTC 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/91M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default) on project integration: Table USER already exists; SQL statement:
[ERROR] CREATE TABLE User
[ERROR] (
[ERROR] id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] userExternalId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] clientId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] clientSecret VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[ERROR] active BOOLEAN,
[ERROR] PRIMARY KEY (id)
[ERROR] )
[ERROR] [42101-180]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

This happens in my `CI` pipeline. I suspect this is happening since the database is present from last run of `mvn clean install`

So I tried  with `${datasource.url}` as

```
<dataSource.url>jdbc:h2:${project.build.outputDirectory}/oauth;create=true</dataSource.url>
```

and

```
<dataSource.url>jdbc:h2:${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/oauth;create=true</dataSource.url>
```

but none of them worked

**Question**
How can I create a **temporary** directory on every run or clean the existing DB using `maven` when running integration tests?

Comment: write a maven plugin - it would be faster than this

Comment: Could you double-check you really call "clean"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ant plugin, you can create a folder during a given phase and then you can remove it during another phase:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ....
            <configuration>
                 <task>
                    <mkdir>./your_directory_to create</mkdir>
                </task>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Try not to use antrun unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Sorry guy, the question is how to create a temporary folder. Do you know another method ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create another instance of the plugin bound to the clean goal, which executes sql to prepare your database for later goals. This sql could, for example, remove tables that were created in the previous build.